# How to apply nested for loop inside a while loop in Clojure?

Tags: python, clojure

It is easy to apply multiple nested for loop inside a while loop in Python. However, it is not the case in Clojure. For my understanding, "for", "while" or "loop"; all of them are macro. Please comment how to write the looping with idiomatic Clojure code ?

```
n = 1
while n < 10:

    for i in range(10):
        print("for loop 1")
        for j in range(10):
            print("for loop 2")

    print("back to loop")

    for j in range(10):
        print("loop3")

    print("back to loop again")
    n += 1
```

for loop does not execute, how to write idiomatic Clojure code?

```
(defn Example []
  (def n (atom 1))
  (while (< @n 10)
    (do
      (println @n)
      ;; for loop does not execute
      (for [i (range 10)]
        (println "for loop 1")
        ;; for loop does not execute
        (for [j (range 10)] (println "for loop 2")))

      (println "back to loop")
      ;; for loop does not execute
      (for [j (range 10)] (println "for loop 3"))
    
      (println "back to loop again")

      (swap! n inc))))

(Example)
```

Comment: Only ever do `def` on namespace level. Use `let` instead. And even better don't use atoms to accumulate some state - most likely loop/recur is what you are after here.

Answer (score 3):

[`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) is lazy. If you are playing with side effects you need to replace him with his cousin [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq).

Some notes on your code:

- a `do` inside a `while` loop is redundant, omit it.
- the `while` loop in both languages isn't really idiomatic. In python it would be another `for` and in clojure [`dotimes`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/dotimes).
- the `(doseq [i (range 10)] ..)` could also be just `(dotimes [i 10] ..)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]]))

(def n (atom 0))

(defn Example
  []
  (while (< @n 2)
    (newline)
    (println "n:" @n)

    ; `for` is lazy, need to force result with `vec`
    (let [nested-result (vec
                          (for [i (range 3)]
                            (do
                              (println "i=" i)
                              (for [j (range 5)] ; lazy execution since no `vec`
                                (do
                                  (println "j=" j)
                                  (+ (* 10 i) j))))))] ; result of nested loops
      (println :nested-result)
      (pprint nested-result))

    (println "back to while")
    ; for loop does not execute
    (doseq [k (range 4)]
      (println "doseq k=" k))

    (println "back to loop again")
    (swap! n inc)))

(dotest
  (Example))
```

with result:

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 15
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

n: 0
i= 0
i= 1
i= 2
:nested-result
[j= 0
j= 1
j= 2
j= 3
j= 4
(0 1 2 3 4) j= 0
j= 1
j= 2
j= 3
j= 4
(10 11 12 13 14) j= 0
j= 1
j= 2
j= 3
j= 4
(20 21 22 23 24)]
back to while
doseq k= 0
doseq k= 1
doseq k= 2
doseq k= 3
back to loop again

n: 1
i= 0
i= 1
i= 2
:nested-result
[j= 0
j= 1
j= 2
j= 3
j= 4
(0 1 2 3 4) j= 0
j= 1
j= 2
j= 3
j= 4
(10 11 12 13 14) j= 0
j= 1
j= 2
j= 3
j= 4
(20 21 22 23 24)]
back to while
doseq k= 0
doseq k= 1
doseq k= 2
doseq k= 3
back to loop again
```

As @xificurC says, use `doseq` for printing or other side effects (or `dotimes`).  A `for` expression is intended to return a result sequence.  Wrap it in a `vec` to avoid the default lazy behavior.

See [this list of documentation](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially "Getting Clojure" and the Clojure CheatSheet.  The template project makes it easy to run the code if you want to try it.

Answer (score 2):

The Clojure documentation addresses this matter in a section on "Clojure's `for`" at https://clojure.org/guides/learn/flow